# Display socket options

Tags: linux, shell

How I can see from shell what socket options are set? In particular 
I'm interesting to know if SO_BROADCAST is set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [See socket options on existing sockets created by other apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618051/see-socket-options-on-existing-sockets-created-by-other-apps)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`lsof(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof).  If `PID` is the process ID and `FD` is the file descriptor number of the socket you're interested in, you can do this:

```
lsof -a -p PID -d FD -T f
```

To list all IPv4 sockets of a process:

```
lsof -a -p PID -i 4 -T f
```

This will print out the socket options with a `SO=`, among other information.  Note that if no options are set, you'll get the empty string, so you'll see something like `SO=PQLEN=0` etc.  To test for `SO_BROADCAST`, just grep for the string `SO_BROADCAST` after the `SO=`, e.g.

```
if lsof -a -p PID -d FD -T f | grep -q 'SO=[^=]*SO_BROADCAST'; then
    # socket has SO_BROADCAST
else
    # it doesn't
fi
```

Comment: On my system (RHEL 5.3) flag "-T" of lsof can accept "q" and "s", but not "f". Is there another solution?

Comment: You can also try `fuser(1)` http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser or `netstat(8)` http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat , but if lsof doesn't work and they don't work, you might be out of luck on your system.

Comment: On Fedora 39, `-T` accepts `f` but silently doesn't print any socket options. AFAICS, lsof, as of 2024, isn't able to print socket options any Linux kernel version.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux, you can use the [knetstat](https://github.com/veithen/knetstat) kernel module to inspect socket options, including `SO_BROADCAST`.

Comment: it is too outdated :(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today; unfortunately, on my system, the `-T` option of `lsof` doesn't accept the `f` flag, and I also didn't want to build the `knetstat` kernel module.

Luckily, I was in the position of being able to `strace` the application while it was setting up the socket, like this:

```sh
strace -e trace=setsockopt -f -o /tmp/log ./program arg1 arg2
```

This traces `./program arg1 arg2`, writing the trace to `/tmp/log`. We only trace the `setsockopt()` system call, which is used to set socket options. The option `-f` makes `strace` also trace any child processes created by the traced program.

If you are lucky, `/tmp/log` will contain lines like this one:

```
18806 setsockopt(60, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
```

This indicates that process `18806` called `setsockopt()` on FD `60` to set `SO_KEEPALIVE` to `1` (enabling it), and that the system call succeeded with return code `0`.

It's also possible to attach to an existing process:

```
strace -e trace=setsockopt -f -o /tmp/log -p PID
```

You can detach from the process using `CTRL-C`, and omit the `-o` option and its argument to send the trace to `stderr`.