# socket.close(fd) in Python. What does 'fd' mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have this piece of code here:

```
import socket
socket.close()
```

I get a warning that socket.close() is missing the 'fd' parameter. What integer should I fill in for general usage, and what do the integers mean?

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't explain in detail. The reason I am asking here on Stack Overflow is that I am not an advanced user. I just want a basic rundown on what it means and how I should use it.

Comment: The package level `close(fd)` function requires a file descriptor of a open socket. So you need the `sock.file_no()` from a socket object to use in that function. The better option is to use the `sock.close()` function on the socket object. You wouldn't need to worry about the file descriptor, it's abstracted by the socket object.

Comment: _Which_ socket do you want to close? `fd` is the ID of _that_ socket.

Comment: Read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html

Comment: Edit: I tried sock.close() itself, and I got this: Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: close() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried looking for a clear explanation but if you're in a bind, the answer mentioned by [rdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62768793/socket-closefd-in-python-what-does-fd-mean#comment110999752_62768793) is probably the best bet. To clarify, if you create a new socket called `my_socket`, then try doing `my_socket.close()`. Based on the official [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example), try something like

```
# Echo client program
import socket
import sys

HOST = 'daring.cwi.nl'    # The remote host
# you need to indicate the host name here
# use
# HOST = socket.gethostbyname("")
# to use '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
my_socket = None
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
    af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    try:
        my_socket = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
    except OSError as msg:
        my_socket = None
        continue
    try:
        my_socket.connect(sa)
    except OSError as msg:
        my_socket.close()
        my_socket = None
        continue
    break
```

While trying to figure this out, I also looked over [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409783/socket-shutdown-vs-socket-close), a lot of which echoes the information from the **[Disconnecting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#disconnecting)** section from the [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#socket-programming-howto) article.

Looking further into the sockets module documentation page, there seems to be [one section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.close) that includes `fd` as an argument, but [another section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) that doesn't... Not sure about this part, so can someone else clarify what;s going on here?

For some more information about sockets in general, check out [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810777/9983575) and this [quick slideshow on sockets and file descriptors](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Emflatt/past-courses/cs5460/lecture17.pdf).

I don't know the optimal solution here and don't understand everything either, so if I made a mistake or there are better resources comment below!

Answer (score 2):

here fd is " File Descriptor" you must know how to handle file descriptor,  the file descriptor fd (an integer as returned by a file object’s fileno() method) and build a socket object from the result.

Comment: Cool. But what number should I use for general socket usage?

Comment: @MacintoshFan read manpage for stdin. see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor